# C# Can I make a picturebox that exists on tab A show on tab B? (winform)

Tags: c#

I have a C# winform app that has a tab control, I have a picturebox on tab A and would like the very same picturebox to appear on tab B. Can this be done?

Thank you
Alison

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just drop a picturebox on tab B as well, and show the same picture there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the picture box to the second tab..

```
tabControl1.TabPages["tabB"].Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
```

This will remove the picture box from tab A and put it, as is, inside tab B.

Edit: you can have this code in the SelectedIndexChanged of the tab control to have the picture box jump between the tabs:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid you can't

I though I could do it once by overriding the designer.cs file to add the control to both tabs and only got an error.

Comment: True, it's not possible to have exact copy of picturebox in both tabs but it's possible to move it between the tabs that achieve the goal here.

Comment: That's true, but what about if both tabs are visible (on two tablists) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either make two pictureboxes, and keep them synchronized, or...

You can get the event to the tab control, OnTabChanged or something like that. If the tab is `Tab A` or `Tab B`, just move the picture box to that tab. I'm not exactly sure how you would do that, but I assume you would just remove it from whereever it is currently, and put it in the right place.